# How to place local commits on top of pulled heads

Tags: mercurial

How do I get my local commits to appear on top of the recently pulled heads?

This is what happended:

1) I made some changes

2) Committed them in my local repository

3) Pulled from the remote repository (now I have 2 eads, one of them being my local changes)

4) How do I place my local changes on top of the other head? I also want to accept all changes from the recently pulled head so that it does not ask me to merge files that haven't been part of the local changesets I made.

Comment: While this might be what you really need to do (Daimrod's answer can help you there), I recommend against "rebasing" your changes. You probably should embrace mercurial way of doing things instead and just merge your changes with the incoming changesets.

Comment: The problem was it was asking me to merge files that I hadn't touched. Those files were never part of any of my changesets that I had committed locally, so I couldn't understand why it was asking me to merge them.

Comment: @sashang becauce these files were part of one of the commits you pulled. By doing this, you're saying "I saw the new changes and I confirm they works fine with my new code". It forces you to acknowledge the fact that those other files were changed since your last push. Even if it's strange at the beginning, I think it's the better way to do things.

Comment: @krtek: Yeah but now I've got a merge commit in my local repo that doesn't make sense to push upstream.

Comment: @sashang it makes perfect sense... It is the proof that you checked that what you're committing works well with what other people did. It forces you to acknowledge the other modification. Have a look at other comments on the accepted answer for some more reason...

Comment: @krtek: I don't think we're on the same page. I'll need to find a way to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [RebaseExtension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RebaseExtension).

### Example:

`hg rebase -b <your head revision> -d <latest pulled commit>`

Will place the set of all your changes from the specified revision (given with -b) and its ancestors up to but not including the common ancestor of the destination revision, on top of the destination revision.

Comment: `rebase` is handy for creating a linear tree, but the *mercurial* way to handle it would be to merge the heads.  If you have merge conflicts, with rebase the resolution gets jammed in with your commits, but by merging you get the resolution separated out into its own revision.

Comment: @sashang: This is an extension because mercurial tries to keep its core small and easy to use. But this extension is maintained by mercurial. See [here](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/UsingExtensions).

Comment: This is never something to "have to do".  Some people choose to make their history inaccurate in order to make it appear linear when it wasn't, but it's never required and frequently not a good idea.  If you don't like seeing a lot of merges in your `hg log` output just use the `--no-merges` option.  Here's a great quote about rebasing and the advisability thereof: http://benjaminfleischer.com/2010/12/02/i-probably-shouldnt-argue-with-linus-torvalds/

Comment: It is an extension because rebasing alters history and can easily cause unexpected problems, e.g. if you rebase something that you have already shared somehow, the old changes will still stick around and they will likely be duplicated. Mercurial core does not include commands that alter history (except for rollback, but that has sufficient safeguards).